# input placeholder value is visible even after actual value is placed in angular2 material

Tags: angular, angular-material

My html file is as shown below:

```
<div style="padding:0 30px 0 30px;">
        <md-form-field style="width:100%;" class="example-full-width">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Card no">
        </md-form-field>
        <div class="q-card-container">
            <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input mdInput placeholder="Exp Month">
            </md-form-field>
            <md-form-field style="margin-left:30px;" class="example-full-width">
                <input mdInput placeholder="Exp Year">
            </md-form-field>
        </div>
        <md-form-field style="width:100%;" class="example-full-width">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Cvv">
        </md-form-field>

    </div>
```

I have used angular2 material design. Aftewr entering value in input output looks like this. [image]

Am I missing anything here to make it work properly?

Comment: Does this happen at all the input fields?

Comment: Yes, it happens with all the input fields

Comment: Version of angular material?

Comment: @Carsten material version 2.0.0-beta.11 , angular version : 4.4.3

Comment: Could you try to set [shouldPlaceholderFloat]="true" to see what it does? My other guess is that you have an error, check your console. edit: Also, check this: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7601

Comment: @Carsten when I wrote shouldPlace in input, it gave me this error `Can't bind to 'shouldPlaceholderFloat' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`

Comment: It's in the documentation... https://material.angular.io/components/input/api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156912/discussion-between-mrugesh-thaker-and-carsten).